# Not displaying items from Cosmos db

Tags: xamarin.forms

I have issuse with my display method. I have been following tutorial on MSToDo items for xamarin. https://github.com/Azure-Samples/azure-cosmos-db-sql-xamarin-getting-started
 I am able to insert in the database so i know it works but cant get anything out of the database. Can you help me please?

this is my get method

```
static DocumentClient docClient = null;

        static readonly string databaseName = "xxxxx";
        static readonly string collectionName = "xxxxx";
        static bool Initialize() //connection
        {
            if (docClient != null)
                return true;

            try
            {
                docClient = new DocumentClient(new Uri(AppConstants.CosmosEndpointUrl), AppConstants.CosmosAuthKey);


            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine(ex);


                docClient = null;

                return false;
            }

            return true;

        }

         public async static Task<List<Post>> GetPosts()
                {
                    var posts = new List<Post>();

                    if (! Initialize())
                        return posts;

                    var postQuery = docClient.CreateDocumentQuery<Post>(
                        UriFactory.CreateDocumentCollectionUri(databaseName, collectionName),
                         new FeedOptions { MaxItemCount = 1, EnableCrossPartitionQuery = true })
                        .OrderBy(i => i.Date)
                        .AsDocumentQuery();

                    while (postQuery.HasMoreResults)
                    {
                        var queryResults = await postQuery.ExecuteNextAsync<Post>();

                        posts.AddRange(queryResults);
                    }

                    return posts;
                }
    public class PostViewModel : BaseViewModel
        {
            List<Post> posts;

            public PostViewModel()
            {
                Posts = new List<Post>();
                RefreshCommand = new Command(async () => await ExecuteRefreshCommand());

            }
            private PostViewModel _selectedAd;
            //private ObservableCollection<Post> _posts;
            public List<Post> Posts { get => posts; set { posts = value; OnPropertyChanged(); } }

            public ICommand RefreshCommand { get; }
      async Task ExecuteRefreshCommand()
            {
                if (IsBusy) return;

                IsBusy = true;

                try
                {
                    Posts = await AdService.GetPosts();
                }
                finally
                {
                    IsBusy = false;
                }
            }
```

}
HOmePage

PostViewModel postViewModel;

```
public HomePage()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    postViewModel = new PostViewModel();
    BindingContext = postViewModel;

}
protected override void OnAppearing()
{
    base.OnAppearing();

    postViewModel.RefreshCommand.Execute(null);


}
```

And my xaml

```
 <ListView  
                        ItemsSource="{Binding Posts}" x:Name="AdLogListView"
                            ItemTemplate="{StaticResource HomePageTemplate}"
                            SelectionMode="Single" Margin="12,0">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Binding Source Path should be Posts and not Post. Your modified xaml would be:-

```
 <ListView  
                        ItemsSource="{Binding Posts}" x:Name="AdLogListView"
                            ItemTemplate="{StaticResource HomePageTemplate}"
                            SelectionMode="Single" Margin="12,0">
```

Comment: yes, just added that and I am getting System.InvalidCastException: 'Specified cast is not valid.'

Comment: PostViewModel postViewModel;

        //private SQLiteConnection _conn;

        public HomePage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            postViewModel = new PostViewModel();
            BindingContext = postViewModel;

        }
        protected override void OnAppearing()
        {
            base.OnAppearing();

            postViewModel.RefreshCommand.Execute(null);


        }

Comment: No idead what happened, but now it works.. I give credit to you for that

Comment: Okay, Thank you! Let me know for further queries.